# how to use function from parent of component TinyMCE init

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce

I have created an upload function inside my parent. When initializing tinymce I have bound the [init] of my component to the loadConfig() function.

```
 <editor [(ngModel)]="data" [init]="loadConfig()"></editor>
```

loadConfig contains the following images_upload_handler:

```
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        const code = this.upload(blobInfo);
        if (code !== 0) {
          success(code);
        } else {
          failure(code);
        }
      }
```

However now when I try to upload something it complains that upload is undefined. I assume that this is the case because the scope of this changed.

I tried listening for the (onInit) event, then replace the function reference with the following code

```
event.editor.settings.images_upload_handler = this.Upload;
```

However now it's complaining that this.apiService is undefined, because I think its still not using the right scope.

I have thought about using an XMLHttpRequest(), but I'm missing security tokes to use that. Also I prefer to use the apiService I created. How do I use the images_upload_handler without losing the scope to my apiService?

Comment: try changing `function (blobInfo, success, failure)` to `(blobInfo, success, failure)=>` to access `this` as currently `this` refers to function scope

Comment: @jitender Thank you, that solves my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I solved this by changing the function to an Arrow function. An arrow function does not have its own bindings to this or super.

```js
images_upload_handler: (blobInfo, success, failure) => {
        const code = this.upload(blobInfo);
        if (code !== 0) {
          success(code);
        } else {
          failure(code);
        }
      }
```